# t-sql multiplying two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables

```
Plant            config         
------         --------

TRZ1            KS

MAS1            MT
```

I would like to have below table with 2 columns

```
RESULT
------
TRZ1  KS

TRZ1  MT

MAS1  KS

MAS1   MT
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear if you want this in the same column, if so then you can concatenate the values using:

```
select p.col1 + ' ' + c.col1 as result
from plant p
outer apply config c
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28782/8)

If not, then you can use:

```
select p.col1 plant, c.col1 config
from plant p
outer apply config c
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28782/7)

Comment: Thanks 2'nd solution is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the shortest way:

```
   select * from plant, config
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use CROSS JOIN:

> SELECT P.NAME, C.NAME FROM Plant AS P CROSS JOIN Config AS C